# How can I restrict some subdomains in cookie?

Tags: java, http, servlets, cookies, httpcookie

Let's assume I have my website on different domains, for example:
 - sub1.domain.com
 - sub2.domain.com
 - domain.com

So, how can I restrict my cookies for sub2.domain.com, but at the same time allow it for sub1.domain.com and domain.com?

Comment: welcome to SO. Question is partly unclear to me, also offtopic [how do i ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 2 domains domain.com and sub1.domain.com can only share cookies if the domain is explicitly named in the Set-Cookie header. Otherwise, the scope of the cookie is restricted to the request host. (Referred to as a "host-only cookie")

If you sent the following header from sub1.domain.com, then the cookie won't be sent for requests to domain.com:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

However if you use the following, it will be usable on both domains:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=domain.com
```